# Is there any good parallel Mixed-Integer Programming optimizer which can run on the Linux?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, optimization

Is there any good parallel Mixed-Integer Programming optimizer which can run on the Linux?
Especially those who provide APIs of high level language, such as Java, C#, or C++

Comment: mixed integer programming - which I believe is a mix between discrete and continuous (linear) programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ILOG CPLEX Optimizer](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), a high-performance mathematical programming solver for linear programming, mixed integer programming, and quadratic programming from IBM,  does exactly what you need.

The latest version (v12.4) provides [deterministic parallel search](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX873.html) and has [API support for various languages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1154.html) including C#, Java and C++. It is free for academic use; otherwise, your option is a trial version before you decide to buy it.

Comment: does this offer an API on the web? from first glance this looks like it runs locally on a desktop computer. the API link you posted is dead.